# How to reject email sent to root@mydomain.tld from external sources in postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix, configuration

I have a postfix mail server correctly configured (I hope) and running on openSUSE 11.3. I can send email to local users from any location, but this also means that I (or anyone else) can send remote emails to the root account. How do I reject remote emails to the root account, while allowing regular users to receive email?

Comment: This is interesting because some systems that detect open relays think that allowing mail to root is equivalent to allowing relaying. This may be because Postfix used to combine the concepts of relay and recipient restrictions:
http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to reject certain addresses is to put this directive in the main.cf file:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
    ...
```

Then on the /etc/postfix/recipient_access file:

```
root@domain REJECT
```

followed by the usual:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_access
```

Comment: This is interesting because some systems that detect open relays think that allowing mail to root is equivalent to allowing relaying. This may be because Postfix used to combine the concepts of relay and recipient restrictions:

Answer (score 1):

I think if you edit /etc/postfix/sender_access and add:

```
root@$mydomain REJECT
```

I'm not entirely sure though.

EDIT: Try using /etc/postfix/header_checks with the "To" header.

Comment: That seems to be useful for rejecting sender addresses and not destination addresses.

Comment: There is a recipient_access file that can be used though.